# Java client with libvirt on Windows

Tags: java, windows, libvirt

I am writing a Java based client that would be executed from Windows that will use libvirt.

1. Got libvirt-java (http://libvirt.org/sources/java/libvirt-java-0.4.7.tar.gz) and build a jar out it (Ant with no params)
2. Then, according to http://libvirt.org/windows.html, built a dll using the “MSYS build script”
3. Got 2 files libvirt-0.dll and libqemu-0.dll

When I run the sample example (in Eclipse) from http://libvirt.org/java.html, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'virt': %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

      at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:169)
      at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:242)
      at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:140)
      at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:368)
      at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:353)
      at org.libvirt.jna.Libvirt.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
      at org.libvirt.Connect.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
      at Main.main(Main.java:26)
```

Also tried instead of step 2 cross compile in Fedora – same error message when I use new dll’s.

Does anybody have any idea how to fix the issue?

Comment: looks like the java part of the library is having problems locating the dlls. Check where the library expects the dlls to be. Does the dlls need to be registered with windows?

Comment: Where you able to resolve this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `jna.library.path` system property value to the path where dll's are located.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you fixed this problem already, but in case you haven't, you need to make a copy of the libvirt-0.dll and rename it libvirt.dll so that the jna can load it, and set the jna.library.path to the directory containing this dll.
Also, I assume this is on 32 bits so you also need to use Java on 32b to compile and execute it